# how to sum sqlite datas per week

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite, cursor

i want to sum the variable "schritte" per week and save it in an extra database

there Im creating my db:

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("myDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
//      db.execSQL("drop table schritte");
        String create = "create table if not exists schritte(bewegung TEXT, dauer TEXT, sdf DATE Default (datetime('now','localtime')));";
        db.execSQL(create);
```

and there is the method whrere i show up the database

```
public void btnHandlerAnzeigen_Schritte(View v) {

        textViewSQLSchritt.setText("");
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from schritte", null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                int schritte = cursor.getInt(0);
                String dauer = cursor.getString(1);
                String date = cursor.getString(2);
                textViewSQLSchritt.append("Schritte:  " + schritte + "  " + dauer + "\n"
                        + date + "\n\n");
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        //here i have tried to make a sum but Im unable to finish it
        Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery("select strftime('%W',_id) as week, sum(value) as total from schritte  GROUP BY week_of_year order by _id desc", null);

    }
```

Comment: Does "an extra database" actually mean "an extra table"? And there are no columns `_id`, `value`, and `week_of_year` in the table you've shown.

Comment: No i need a second database where the sum of the week is saved. Yes but it also works without _id

Comment: There is no variable `schritte`. What do you want to add? The number of records?

Comment: oh sorry i meant the variable `bewegung`

Comment: You probably don't need a new database, you need a new table in an existing database. You can not (*) select values from a table in a different database which means that you stop yourself from combining your data in useful ways.  ( * you can attach them)